# only photo_file_name displays in the place of photo

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have attached photo successfully in my rails 2.3.5 application. But when tries to display the photo, only photo_file_name comes. I checked in console whether getting the URL correctly. URL is correct. 
   I have following in my view

```
<% if @employee.photo.file? %>
  <%= image_tag @employee.photo.url %>
<%else %>
  <%= image_tag "HR/default_employee.png" %>
<%end%>
```

else part works fine.

Comment: Please check your development.rb file. It should have `config.serve_static_assets = true`. If it's false make it true.

Comment: getting no method error #undefined method `serve_static_assets='

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there's permission problem, use `chmod` to permit read and write operations for the directory where you are saving your pictures, use the following command in terminal

```
chmod 777 directory_path
```